How "rare" is the isomorphism $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n) \cong \mathbb{Z}_n^*$ in rings?
(This is really a request for example-collection.)
If $C_n$ denotes the cyclic group of order $n$, then there is the age-old isomorphism
$$
\operatorname{Aut}(C_n) \cong \mathbb{Z}_n^*
$$
the right-hand side denoting the group of units of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Recasting this a bit, we can replace $C_n$ by the additive group $(\mathbb{Z}_n, +)$, which is of course the underlying additive group of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$ which appears on the right-hand side of our isomorphism. Recasting again, let's write $U(R)$ for the underlying additive group of a ring $R$ with identity.  Then our isomorphism above becomes
$$
\operatorname{Aut}(U(\mathbb{Z}_n)) \cong \mathbb{Z}_n^*
$$
which is a statement about the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$.  In mucking around with ideas like this, I don't immediately see other examples of this phenomenon, where a ring determines its own automorphism group of the additive group via its group of units.    The only other immediate example is $\mathbb{Z}$.
So, are there other rings $R$ with identity so that
$$
\operatorname{Aut}(U(R)) \cong R^*
$$
and is it possible to say something informative about such rings?  (Necessary structural properties, total classification, etc.)

To be specific, there's a natural map $R^* \to \operatorname{Aut}(U(R))$ where $u \mapsto (x \mapsto ux)$ which is obviously injective.  Are you asking when that specific map is surjective?

I wasn't thinking that way, but I suppose I am.

If you're already using the (perfectly good) notation $R^*$ for a ring's multiplicative group, I recommend using $R^+$ for its additive group rather than introducing a new letter and parentheses for it.

As already mentioned in the comments, it is more interesting to ask when the canonical(!) homomorphism of groups
$$R^{\times} \to \mathrm{Aut}(R,+), \quad u \mapsto (x \mapsto ux)$$
is an isomorphism. This is quite rare. Here is a small indicator. I will focus on commutative rings, otherwise we also need to ask ourselves what happens with additive automorphisms of the form $x \mapsto xu$ where $u \in R^{\times}$.
Let $R$ be a commutative ring of prime characteristic $p$ with this property, and $R \neq 0$. Then $R$ becomes a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$. For every non-zero $r \in R$ there is some automorphism of the vector space mapping $1 \to r$. By assumption, $r$ then has to be a unit. Thus, $R$ is a field. Assume that $r \in R \setminus \mathbb{F}_p$. Then $1,r$ are linearly independent, and also $1,r^{-1}$. Hence, there is some additive automorphism mapping $1 \mapsto 1$ and $r \mapsto r^{-1}$. So by assumption there is some $u \in R^{\times}$ with $1=u1$ and $r^{-1} = ur$. Thus, $r^{-1}=r$, i.e. $r = \pm 1$, a contradiction. Thus, $R \cong \mathbb{F}_p$ as rings.
An even stronger, but perhaps more natural condition would be to demand that the canonical homomorphism of rings
$$R \to \mathrm{End}(R,+), \quad u \mapsto (x \mapsto ux)$$
is an isomorphism (notice that the latter is a ring since $\mathbf{Ab}$ is additive). Again, this is satisfied for $R = \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (you wrote $\mathbb{Z}_n$, a notation which is already reserved for the ring of $n$-adic integers, so better don't use that), but not for many other rings.
These rings have been discussed at Rings that are isomorphic to the endomorphism ring of their additive group. (and it seems that a person who shares my name has written an answer there 10 years ago which I need to study now). So whenever the unique homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to R$ is an epimorphism in the categorical sense, the property is satisfied.
